# I need to pull only one record from the table where it satisifies my condition of Minimum period Id and the forecast value greater than zero

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My requirement is to pull only single set of record from the table where it should satisfy my condition of minimum period id from the table with Depot wise forecast > 0

I tried with the below code but it is pulling the sum of depot wise forecast of all periods. Ideally I should get only one record with it is the minimum period in the table and forecast value > 0

This code is pulling all the set of records from the table with forecast > 0

```
SELECT MIN(period_id) AS PERIOd_ID, DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST 
FROM disaggregate_data 
WHERE snop_item = '01NV2'     
  AND fulfillment_center = 'TIL'  
  AND DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST > 0
GROUP BY PERIOD_ID, DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST
```

This code is pulling the sum of forecast value of all periods in the table

```
SELECT MIN(dd.period_id), SUM(depot_wise_forecast)
FROM disaggregate_data DD (nolock)  
WHERE dd.DEPOT_WISE_FORECAST > 0    
  AND snop_item = '01NV2' 
  AND fulfillment_center = 'TIL'
```

I expect only one  minimum period id and depot wise forecast pulled from the table with forecast value > 0

Comment: Removed the `plsql` tag - that's PL/SQL in Oracle, but this question obviously is about **SQL Server** and it's SQL language "dialect" is **T-SQL**

Comment: Can you clarify your question by adding sample input and output data?

Comment: I have my data in a table called XYZ. I need to extract the columns from the table on a condition such that the period is minimum and the forecast is greater than o.

Comment: PERIOD ID  NAME FORECAST
112 klim 0
113 nome 12
114 jame 15
115 watt 18
116 kinse 20
117 lakin 22
118 norme 16
119 jackie 14                                                                    now i need to pull only one record where  period id is minimum and the forecast value >0

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you *... need to pull only one record where period id is minimum and the forecast value >0 ...*, the next approach may help.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ (
   PERIODID int,
   NAME varchar(10),    
   FORECAST int
)
INSERT INTO XYZ
   (PERIODID, NAME, FORECAST)
VALUES
   (112, 'klim', 0),
   (113, 'nome', 12), 
   (114, 'jame', 15), 
   (115, 'watt', 18), 
   (116, 'kinse', 20), 
   (117, 'lakin', 22), 
   (118, 'norme', 16), 
   (119, 'jackie', 14)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT PERIODID, NAME, FORECAST
FROM (
   SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PERIODID) AS RN
   FROM XYZ
   WHERE FORECAST > 0
) t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Output:

```
PERIODID    NAME    FORECAST
113         nome    12
```